# Gridlines between discrete values

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using a discrete values ggplot2 provides a gridline at the tick value at the centre of the value

```
library(reshape2)

ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

How can I set the grid line from the x axis to appear between the discrete values (i.e. between 'Dinner' and 'Lunch')

I have tried to set `panel.grid.minor.x` however (I think) as it is discrete this does not work ... this is not a minor value for it to plot the girdline on.

```
ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line())
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add a vertical line that will act as a grid line as follows:

```
geom_vline(xintercept=1.5, colour='white')
```

You can, of course, alter line width, colour, style, etc. as needed, and add multiple lines in the appropriate locations if you have several groups of bars that need to be separated by grid lines. For example, using some fake data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(total_bill=rnorm(100,80,10), 
                 sex=rep(c("Male","Female"),50),
                 time=sample(c("Breakfast","Brunch","Lunch","Afternoon Tea","Dinner"), 
                             100, replace=TRUE))
dat$time = factor(dat$time, 
                  levels=c("Breakfast","Brunch","Lunch","Afternoon Tea","Dinner"),
                  ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1.5, length(unique(dat$time))-0.5, 1), 
             lwd=1, colour="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually using `facet_grid` with `scales='free_x'` so using `length` like this is problematic. I've had a look but cant find how to get the count of ticks in each facet.

Comment: If your free scale is numeric or an ordered factor, you can use `max(dat$var_name)` instead of `length(unique(dat$var_name))`. Does that help, or is your situation more complicated than that?

Comment: code that works with plain boxplot, fails with `facet_grid` unfortunately: `! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. My solution was to make the grid line bigger ..

```
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(total_bill=rnorm(100,80,10), 
                 sex=rep(c("Male","Female"),50),
                 time=sample(c("Breakfast","Brunch","Lunch","Afternoon Tea","Dinner"), 
                             100, replace=TRUE))
dat$time = factor(dat$time, 
                  levels=c("Breakfast","Brunch","Lunch","Afternoon Tea","Dinner"),
                  ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, color=sex)) +
  geom_point(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "white", size = 20))
```